# How to get rid of 'salt & pepper' noise on empty (dark) image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mean, mask

I am working on a diy image fluorometer (it measures fluorescence from plants) which measures the average intensity of pixels within a binary mask. At first, the fluorometer captures the mask and stores it. On a second run, while the lights are off, the script starts and saves the cv2.mean() results on a csv; after few seconds the lights go on and the measurement as such starts. The reason to start the measurement while the lights are off is that we need the baseline (or dark image). The problem I've got, is that while the light is off, the masked image contains 'salt and pepper' noise, as opposed to a black (zero) image, and that is distorting my measurements. See a couple of images of a small cactus with light on (full fluorescence) and with the light off (salt & pepper).

My question is, is it possible to get rid of that noise?

I am using a raspberry pi compute module at the moment, but this is originally meant to run on a Jetson TX2, which is waiting for a carrier board. More info at:

[DIY Fluorometer](https://hackaday.io/project/174580-a-diy-imaging-fluorometer)

[image: Actinic light on]

[image]

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import csv


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_V4L)

cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2 + cv2.CAP_V4L) # Thermal camera

# CU51 has the following possible resolution settings
# 640 x 480
# 1280 x 720
# 1920 x 1080
# 2592 x 1944


rows = 640
cols = 480

# Set parameters for the camera
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cols)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, rows)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0) # turn off RGB conversion
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 5)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 1) #Not Supported
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'Y16 '))
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('fluorescence_1.raw',fourcc, int(cap.get(5)), (int(cap.get(4)), int(cap.get(3))))

# Grab capture value (into null) and frame
_, frame = cap.read()

# CU51 camera
# convert from 12 bit (4096 levels) to 8 bit (256 levels)   255/4096 = 0.06226
# bf8 = np.array(frame,dtype = np.uint16) # Using unit16 here
bf81 = np.array(frame//16, dtype = np.uint8)

# Create the mask
binary = cv2.imread('Masked_Image.png')
binary = binary[:,:,1]
#_, binary = cv2.threshold(bf81, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print('Width = ', cap.get(3),' Height = ', cap.get(4),' fps = ', cap.get(5))

original_stdout = sys.stdout

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    _, frame2 = cap2.read()
# CU51 camera
# convert from 12 bit (4096 levels) to 8 bit (256 levels) 255/4096 = 0.06226
# bf8 = np.array(frame,dtype = np.uint16) # Using here unit16

bf8 = np.array(frame//16, dtype = np.uint8)
im3 = cv2.bitwise_and(bf8,binary)
im3[binary==0] = 0

# Normalize the image
bf8_2 = cv2.normalize(im3, None, 0.0, 1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
# bf8_3 = cv2.normalize(bf8, None, 0.0, 1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
bf8_2_color = cv2.applyColorMap(im3, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
bf8_3_color = cv2.applyColorMap(frame2, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
cv2.imwrite('Masked_Image.png', binary)

# Display the image, print image size and fps and save each frame
#cv2.imshow('Original Frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('Masked_Image', bf8_2)
cv2.imshow("lepton", cv2.resize(bf8_3_color, (640, 480)))
cv2.imshow("Opencv Video See3Cam_CU51 Color", bf8_2_color)
#cv2.imshow('Opencv Video See3Cam_CU51', bf8_3)
cv2.imshow('Opencv Binary Image', binary)
print('Pixels =', cv2.countNonZero(im3))
print('Mean =', cv2.mean(bf8_2, im3)[:1])
print('Standard Deviation =', cv2.meanStdDev(bf8_2, im3)[:1])

with open('Results1.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Mean']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    #writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Mean': cv2.mean(bf8_2, im3)[:1]})

# detect waitkey of q to quit
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

[image: Fluorescence trace]
[image: DIY Fluorometer]

Comment: There are many different variants how to rid of noise on an image. 1) Just using ```erode``` method. 2) Using ```erode``` and then ```dilate``` 3) Parse object on a binary image and remove small objects under a threshold

Comment: don't worry if the previous comment makes no sense to you. it doesn't to me either ;) -- so you're trying to calculate a synthetic long exposure from video frames. that's doable. look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-frame_subtraction -- *do* present your methods, not just your pictures. we don't know how exactly those were made. it's impossible to fix something you aren't allowed to see.

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, many thanks for your comment. I have added the code, another picture to illustrate what I see while the script is running and a link to more background info. I will double check your link and see how I can implement it using opencv/python.

Comment: Why do you normalize the frame if you want to measure the average intensity? If you don't normalize, then your no-lights picture will be nice and dark as you'd expect. Make sure your camera exposure time is set to a fixed value, that it doesn't adjust exposure during your experiment.

Comment: @CrisLuengo now we are cooking with gas! That worked flawlessly.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo the mask is still showing some noise, is not entirely black (or zero), do you have any idea of why?

Comment: Do you mean the “lights off” condition? That’s not expected to be zero. Or are you talking about “Masked_Image.png”?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, I meant lights off. The image with no mask gives zero, while the masked image gives around 10 (0-255 scale).

Comment: Cameras tend to have an offset. You should be able to configure this offset in the camera settings. But the offset is good, as it allows proper characterization of noise and so on. The "no lights" image tells you exactly what the offset is. Within the cactus region, you should measure maybe some level of phosphoresce? In the region of the image where there's no cactus is where you should measure the offset. The mean value there you should subtract from all your measurements.

Comment: I noticed that you use the "jet" color map. Please don't use it. People have shown 40 years ago how incredibly bad it is for visualization, I don't understand how it is still used. OpenCV has (I just looked) better color maps in `COLORMAP_PARULA` (copied from MATLAB) and `COLORMAP_VIRIDIS` (copied from Matplotlib). If you really need a rainbow color map, use `COLORMAP_TURBO`, which at least doesn't have the terrible banding that "jet" and similar rainbow color maps have.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo, thanks for your comments above. I am just curious as to why the 'offset' is just noticeable within the masked image, as the unmasked image with lights off will show zero overall. I can live with it though, is not a big deal, I can assume the 10 as 0, unless it will clearly affect my measurements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have added a couple of images to the original post to illustrate the results of each experiment. Image visualisation is not important for me really, what matters the most is the data recorded in the csv file, which I plot. The peaks are basically strong light pulses that saturate the plant, while the peak that decreases is an 'actinic' light on of around 500 umoles that the plant quenches (Kautsky effect). The problem is that I need to calculate F0 which is tricky because I need another light that is very weak (< 1 umoles).

Comment: Do you measure something different after masking, or is it that you see it by eye? An image with a value of 10 everywhere looks all black, an image that is all zero and has a region with value 10 does not look all black. Perception of black depends on a reference. Forget what you see, this is about what you measure. If you leave the cap on the camera lens, yo I measure the offset. Subtract that value from all your intensity measurements.